# Primeng : Select dropdown value with keyboard in model driven form group

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng

I have a `formGroup` with a `formControlName` attached on a dropdown of Primeng, all works perfectly exept when I try to select an option in the dropdow with the keyboard.

If you couple a required this dropdown to a button which is disabled while the formGroup is not valid :

```
<button pButton type="button" [label]="'Login'" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid"></button>
```

This button never become active if I select a value in the dropdown selection with the keyboard. 
In my page, I focus the dropdown element with tab key, and chose a value by using arrow keys. The selected value is displayed in the dropdown but the `formGroup.value` corresponding to the dropdown still empty...

I don't understand why and how I can fix that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this It's working using keyboard up and down arrow based on dropdown value :

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Select</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="list_dropdown" id="list_dropdown" formControlName="list_dropdown">
            <option value="" >Select...</option>
            <option value="list1">list1</option>
            <option value="list2">list2</option>
            <option value="list3">list3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button pButton type="button" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid" label="Login"></button>
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
loginForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            list_dropdown: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
        })
    }
```